# How to get quote_id from sales order page of admin in magento?

Tags: magento

Is it possible to get quote_id of an specific order in admin->sales->orders->view(select particular order) page ?

I want to show my custom table(which contain quote_id for an order) data in admin->sales->view(select particular order) gift option block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the order itself has `quote_id`, you can retrieve it in this way:

```
// supposing order id is 1
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(1);
$quoteId = $order->getQuoteId();
```

if you need to retrieve `quote` object, you can get it by:

```
$quoteObject = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteId);
```